# writing a method to calculate income tax. Variable not initializing

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

I am writing a method to calculate income tax based on gross pay and number of dependents. When I try and compile the following code, my dTaxOnIncome variable is getting not initialized.

```
    public static double incomeTax(double gross, int dependents)
{
            double dTaxOnIncome;                // holds the calculated income tax.

            if(gross >= 10000 && dependents == 0)
            {
                dTaxOnIncome = gross * .25; 
            }
            else
            {   
                if((gross >= 10000) && ((dependents >= 1 && dependents <= 4)))
                {
                    if(dependents == 1)
                    {
                        dTaxOnIncome = gross * .24;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(dependents == 2)
                        {   
                            dTaxOnIncome = gross * .23; 
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if(dependents == 3)
                            {
                                dTaxOnIncome = gross * .22; 
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(dependents == 4)
                                {
                                    dTaxOnIncome = gross * .21; 
                                }
                                else 
                                {   
                                    if(dependents == 5)
                                    {
                                        dTaxOnIncome = gross * .205; 
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        if(dependents == 6)
                                        {
                                            dTaxOnIncome = gross * .20; 
                                        }
                                        else 
                                        {
                                            if(dependents > 6)
                                            {
                                                dTaxOnIncome = gross * .18;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {   
                                            }   

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    return dTaxOnIncome;    
}// end incomeTax (double, int)
```

I know that I could use if else statements, but I have tried this problem multiple ways and this seemed to be the most straight forward.

Comment: Edit the line to `double dTaxOnIncome = 0.0 ; `

Comment: What if neither of these conditions will be met? What value should be returned? What makes you think that Java should know that value?

Comment: Don't misquote error messages. That's not what it says. Look again. Understand what it really says and you have your solution.

Answer (score 2):

Local variables in Java need to get implicitly initialized before they can be used. In your code, you did not initialize the variable dTaxOnIncome beforehand so java tries to see if you initialize it later on but it turns out your variable does not get initialized at certain places so Java is considering those situations. In those cases of execution, accessing the value is a problem.

> You can add some default value in the declaration

this will make your code work and if you don't wanna make default value then make sure that your variables get initialized no matter what execution path your program takes.

Comment: "everywhere except the last else block" is not true, there are two scenarios where it is not initialized. The other is when the following is false: `if((gross >= 10000) && ((dependents >= 1 && dependents <= 4)))`

Comment: Oh yeah thanks for bringing it to my notice. I replied from mobile and was not able to see the code fully.

Comment: You're welcome, but "the one situation when your code goes into the last else block and the variable will not be initialized" is still a bit misleading

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double incomeTax(double gross, int dependents){
       double dTaxOnIncome=0.0;
       // if gross is less than 10000 there is no tax deduction
       if(gross<10000) return dTaxOnIncome;

       //gross is larger or equal to 10000
       //calculate tax deduction according to number of depedents

       if(dependents==0){
           dTaxOnIncome = gross * .25; 
       }
       if(dependents==1){
           dTaxOnIncome = gross * .24; 
       }
       if(dependents==2){
           dTaxOnIncome = gross * .23;  
       }
       if(dependents==3){
           dTaxOnIncome = gross * .22; 
       }
       if(dependents==4){
           dTaxOnIncome = gross * .21; 
       }
       if(dependents==5){
           dTaxOnIncome = gross * .205; 
       }
       if(dependents==6){
           dTaxOnIncome = gross * .20; 
       }           
       if(dependents>6){
          dTaxOnIncome = gross * .18; 
       }

       return dTaxOnIncome;

}
```